# How to convert SQL into activerecord Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, activerecord

My sql that gives me the results I want (a single record from books table).

```
select * 
from books
where book_number = ? and id not in (select book_id from checkout_logs where returned_date is null) limit 1
```

my best active record attempt:

```
@book = Book.where(book_number: params[:book_number]).where.not(id: CheckoutLog.where(returned_date: nil)).find(1)
```

? is the params[:book_number]

here is my Rails schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_12_30_171415) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "books", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "author"
    t.string "genre"
    t.string "subgenre"
    t.integer "pages"
    t.string "publisher"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "book_number"
  end

  create_table "checkout_logs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "checkout_date"
    t.datetime "due_date"
    t.datetime "returned_date"
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.bigint "book_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["book_id"], name: "index_checkout_logs_on_book_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_checkout_logs_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.boolean "admin", default: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "checkout_logs", "books"
  add_foreign_key "checkout_logs", "users"
end
```

The idea is I want to get a single book (id) from the book table with a given book_number (think ISBN) that doesn't have a record in checkout_log table with a matching book_id and a null for returned_date. (indicating a book is checked out and not available.)

**EDIT:** changed the last part from .take to .find(1) which now does take 1 record, problem is the

```
.where.not(id: CheckoutLog.where(returned_date: nil))
```

part isn't filtering out the books which have a checkout_log record and no returned_date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.where.not(id: CheckoutLog.where(returned_date: nil))`

=> I think you are filtering wrong id, you need to filter by book's id, not id of CheckoutLog.

So your query should be:

`.where.not(id: CheckoutLog.where(returned_date: nil).pluck(:book_id))`

Comment: I was able to get it working using that and .take or .first at the end, but .find(1) and limit(1) both gave (different) errors and don't work in this case. Apparently this is limitation to how pluck works. Either way, it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use of the `includes` query method may help.

`Book.includes(:checkout_logs).where("books.book_number=? AND checkout_logs.returned_date IS NOT NULL", params[:book_number]).limit(1)`

More info on query methods is [in the api](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes)

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. As is it was giving me more than 1 book. I had issues using limit(1) before, so I changed it to .first and .take and they gave me a different error( missing from clause). Following your link it mentions that include is used to 'Specify relationships to be included in the result set'. In this case I don't need checkout_logs in the result set. I just want a single book from the book table.